# How do I improve socket server performance

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have built an intermediate socket server with Nodejs which acts as a mediator between backend Web-sockets server and the client. [image]

When too many events are received from backend, there occurs a considerable delay in relaying the event to client. This happens due to queueing of later events.

How do I stop the current event execution and execute the latest event?

Comment: The performance of your proxy will be entirely dependent upon your node.js code so it's unlikely we can offer much real info without seeing the relevant portions of the code.  Also, it would help to know why you're using a proxy in the first place?  What is its main function?

Comment: It's main function is to move business logic from UI to this proxy server. So the logic for processing of data happens to reside on this server.

Comment: And my doubt is regarding a plain socket event listener implementation. `socket.on('eventA', handlerforEventA);` So if the eventA occurs very rapidly, how do I give the most recent event the priority? Because for now, it seems to be queued.